# Apache POI is not returning the right number of sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, spreadsheet

I am using Apache POI to work with spreadsheets and I need to throw an exception if the spreadsheet has more than one sheet. The problem is that if the file is a .xlsx it works fine, but if the file is .xls it always give the size of 0. This is the code:

```
public void validateSpreadsheet(String ext) {
if (ext.equals("xls") || ext.equals("xlsx") || ext.equals("xlsm")) {
   Workbook myWorkBook;
                try {
                    if (ext.equals("xls")) {
                        myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                    } else {
                        myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    }

                } catch (POIXMLException ex) {
                    throw ProdutoExceptions.OOXML_NOT_ALLOWED;
                }
                if(myWorkBook.getNumberOfSheets() > 1){
                    throw ProdutoExceptions.INVALID_NUMBER_OF_SHEETS;
                }
}
```

Comment: Hmm you are just creating a new empty workbook, how it is supposed to contain sheets?

Comment: The code is just an adaptation of what I am doing. I ensure that it is receving something.

Comment: You need to post actual code a [mcve], that's the only way to get a decent answer

Answer (score 1):

renams, ensure that you are using HSSF to read the .xls and XSSF to .xlsx files

HSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 97-2007 (.xls) file format.
XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 (.xlsx) file format.